# Windows 10 cant copy

Tags: images, file-transfer

I have created an image for my freshly installed Windows 10 last year,
I want to format my laptop now.

I am trying to copy this image (11GB) to an external harddisk so i can use it to resotre windows.

The problem is that when I try to copy the image folder I get "calculating" for an hour then nothing happens

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Try using a different external drive

Comment: @Ramhound He already mentioned he's using external HDD

Comment: @RahulKurup - Please read my comment again, I suggested the author, use a **different** external drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why, but when I copied the image to the desktop then copied it from the desktop to the extrenal drive it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use command copy in elevated command promt. For example:

```
copy C:\Users\desktop\image.wim D:\backup\image.wim
```